# ASP.NET Web API Repository Pattern Service Layer (Business Logic)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, business-logic

I just finish to implement Repository Pattern & Unit of Work using Ninject Dependency Injection into my asp.net web api project.

Im using Entity Framework as my ORM.

I have the following soluction structure (projects):

- Web Application (asp.net web api)
- Data (DBContext, Repositories)
- Interfaces (IRepository, etc)
- Model (POCO Classes from DB)

So for example my PersonRepository (Data project):

```
    public class PersonsRepository : EFRepository<Person>, IPersonsRepository
            {
                public PersonsRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

                public IQueryable<Person> GetByAge(int age)
                {
                     return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.age == age);

                }

     public void Delete(int personId, int age)
            {
                // Here I want to validate some stuff before deleting
                // Business Rules need to be here!!

                var attendance = new Attendance {PersonId = personId, Age = age};
                Delete(attendance);
            }

            }
```

So my question is if its correct to implement all the business logic inside my Repository Methods? and also what is the best way to return a message or validation in case I need to.

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

There should be a new layer between Data and Web called Business. Web will reference Business layer only and Business layer will reference Data layer only. So the Business layer before or after calling the Data layer can implement all its validation and business logic.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. The repository implementation belongs to persistence (DAL). Repository is concerned with 'converting' business objects to/from whatever form used to store them into the database. It isn't its responsibility to care about business logic. Business logic stays in the business layer, in the domain.

Business logic is contained by domain objects and services. It never gets outside the business layer, not in UI (controllers) not in DAL (repositories, EF etc).

The repository implementation you're using is incorrect, an anti-pattern, as it defeats the purpose of a repository: to decouple the business layer from the persistence details (EF is an implementation detail). The repository's interface should never expose details like IQueryable or EF entities. It should 'know' only about business objects.

Your solution structure makes little sense to me: all interfaces you're using should be in the layer they belong to(repository interface is part of business layer, that's why it shouldn't know about EF). The Model, based on your description seems to be the persistence model (it should be part of Data).

You want a Business(Domain) layer where Model really means business model. Not to be confused with persistence model(used by EF), view model(used by a View) or the M from MVC (used by Controllers) :) . The M from MVC refers to parts of the business model but it's not the same thing as the business model.

I suggest to take your time and read a bit more about repository pattern and 3-tier architecture and make sure you've understood the concepts and their purpose.

Comment: Actually I took as reference the John Papa Code Camper project: https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper

In the sample code I have, that repository pattern is a custom implementation for a custom repository... because the method GetByAge will only be used by PersonRepo

Comment: So what you told me is that the Business rules or logic (to check if some field is correct of if a condition is true or what ever should go in the Model project (where I have my POCO Classes) ?

Comment: Business logic should stay in business logic layer, not in data acccess

Comment: @MikeSW - I'm just learning about repositories and MVC. Could you point me to a good reference/tutorial? Thanks. Mark